# Can't get Ubuntu to work properly on my desktop

Tags: boot, pcie

So, I've been trying for quite some time to get Ubuntu running on my Dell XPS8900, but it's been hard. I have ubuntu installed already in a partition on my HD alongside with Windows. At first, NVidia drivers were the problem, but they were successfully installed. Now, I can't even boot to Ubuntu. My display goes black and floods the following message: "PCIe Bus Error: severity=corrected". I already tried adding the boot parameters pcie_aspm=off, pci=noaer and pci=nomsi, but I had no success. The first one doesn't appear to do anything, while the latter get me to a screen with a single blinking "_". I tried installing ubuntu on a second SSD after disconnecting all other devices from my motherboard, but then I had no success in running the installer (got the exact same error). Can someone help me? What can I do to get it working?

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5X2FI.jpg)

EDIT: I got it to work by disabling intel SpeedStep on the bios and adding the pcie_aspm=off parameter.

Comment: Before anything else update UEFI. Then disable Secure Boot (UEFI) and Fast Startup (Windows). Other UEFI settings may need to be changed.

Comment: It may help if you mention what release of Ubuntu you're using; it gives us a clue as to the software stack you're trying to use.

Comment: Hi! I'm using 20.04 LTS. I got it to work by disabling Intel SpeedStep on the BIOS and adding the pcie_aspm=off parameter to the boot. Thank you very much! I'll add it to my question so that it helps people with the same issue.